# Is there a bijection between the set of simple closed curves and this space of functions?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, curves-and-surfaces

A simple closed curve $\mathcal{C}$  in the plane is such that, going along the curve from a point $P$ thereon and getting back to it, the total angle has measure $2\pi$. So one can write $2\pi=\int_{\mathcal{C}} d\theta=\int_{\mathcal{C}}\dfrac{d\theta}{ds}ds=\int_{\mathcal{C}}C(s)ds$ where $C(s)$ is the curvature and $s$ the abscissa on the curve. Of course $C$ is continuous and $T$-periodic for $T=\int_{\mathcal{C}}ds$.

So let's consider the space $S(T)$ of all $T$-periodic continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ $f$ such that $\int_{0}^{T}f(t)dt=2\pi$.

Is there a bijection between the set of all simple closed planar curves of perimeter $T$ and $S(T)$?

Comment: Well, both sets have the size of a continuum, so, yes, there is a bijection. It is not clear what do you want from this bijection?

Comment: I want to map the curve whose curvature is $s\mapsto f(s)$ to $f$. That way, to the circle of radius $R$ is associated the constant function $x\mapsto\frac{1}{R}$.

Comment: Are you asking whether or not every function in $S(T)$ comes from the curvature of a simple closed curve?

Comment: Yes, and the other way around too.

Comment: The answer is no, i.e., the map which takes a curve to its curvature is not onto. You have the additional condition that the integral over the tangent vector is 0, where the tangent vector is $exp(i F)$, $F$ being the integral of $f$. The later condition is not always satisied.

Comment: What does it mean geometrically? No cusp or any other kind of singular point?

Comment: It is a translational period, as you can see in the example of a nodary curve, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodary.

Comment: Maybe you can turn your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it and the question get closed.